# First cgi script in perl and don't know what it does

Tags: perl, apache, cgi

I am new to Perl and I am looking into CGI programs.
I tried the following from [Perl Monks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=44536) and it works. But I have no idea what it does.
1) What is the `END_HERE`? that is followed by `HTML`? :

```
print <<END_HERE;   
<html>  
  <head>  
    <title>My First CGI Script</title>  
  </head>  
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">  
    <h1>This is a pretty lame Web page</h1>  
    <p>Who is this Ovid guy, anyway?</p>   
  </body>   
</html>  
END_HERE
```

2) I modified the sample script by adding:

```
my $query = new CGI;  
my $p= $query->param('myparam');
```

I.e. the new script is:

```
#!C:\perl\bin\perl.exe -wT
use strict;
use CGI;

my $query = new CGI;


print $query->header( "text/html" );

my $time = $query->param('fromDate');

print <<END_HERE;  
   <html>  
     <head>  
       <title>My First CGI Script $time</title>  
     </head>  
     <body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">  
       <h1>This is a pretty lame Web page</h1> 
       <p>Who is this Ovid guy, anyway?</p> 
     </body>  
   </html>  
END_HERE  


# must have a line after "END_HERE" or Perl won't recognize
# the token
```

It stopped working. I get the following error message:

```
Undefined subroutine &main::param called at C:/.../test2.cgi line 10.
```

How can I get the parameters send by the browser if not this way?

Comment: @ikegami:`[Mon May 13 00:00:58 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Undefined subroutine &main::param called at C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache2/cgi-bin/test2.cgi line 10.`

Comment: @ikegami:Concerning your `END_HERE` comment, I don't understand what you are saying. :(

Comment: You didn't get that error from the code you showed.

Comment: @ikegami:Line 10 is `my $p= $query->param('myparam');`

Comment: Not in the version of the script that gave that error. That error comes from a sub call, but you're saying it came from a method call.

Comment: @ikegami:Posted new script in case it helps

Comment: Post the new error message too...

Comment: If I may say, CGI.pm is an old technology. If you are able you should look into a modern framework like [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) or [Dancer](http://perldancer.org). It can run in the same way that CGI scripts do, but its much easier.

Comment: @ikegami:There is no new error msg.This is the script I am running for this OP

Comment: That script cannot result in that error, as I've already explained. You never call `param` as a sub -- you call it as a method -- yet that error can only come from calling `param` as a sub. Either you posted the wrong code or the wrong error. Please fix this.

Comment: As noted in the answers, there are errors in the script you posted, but simply not the one you claim to be getting.

Answer (score 2):

```
... <<END_HERE ...
foo
bar
END_HERE
```

means

```
... "foo
bar
" ...
```

The choice of terminator is up to you. You can use any bareword or any string if you add quotes. Both the following are equivalent to `"foo\nbar\n"`:

```
<<MEOW
foo
bar
MEOW

<<"And they lived happily ever after."
foo
bar
And they lived happily ever after.
```

---

The script you posted has two problems, neither of them resulting in the error you specified.

1. Perl can't find the end of the here-doc since no line contains solely `END_HERE`. You have one that contains `END_HERE` with a whole bunch of leading spaces, but that's not the same thing. Remove the leading spaces.
2. It allows an arbitrary string to be placed in the HTML. Do escape (using, say, [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aEntities)'s `encode_entities`)! Consider what happens if someone passes the following to the `fromDate` parameter:

   ```
   <script>alert("owned")</script>
   ```

Comment: +1.Interesting but actually I don't have leading spaces in `END_HERE`. It is a copy-paste issue

Comment: It still has trailing spaces. Post the code you ACTUALLY ran (which is to say, run the code you actually posted.) Post the output you ACTUALLY got.

Comment: I have problem with the formating in the post.What I can tell you is the following.I created a new file and I copy-pasted the working cgi.I.e. I have 2 cgi files that are identical.If I call the first cgi it works.If I call the second I get no response.I can not understand what am I messing up.What other information would be needed in the post?